# Linearise non-linear ODE two degree of freedom

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to get a linearised matrix system of the following non-linearised ODE system, with two degree of freedom. My approach has been using Taylor expansion for the $B + x_2^C$ denominator but I get an even messier expression instead...

Any guidance on how I should re-tackle this?

$$
\dfrac{dx_1}{dt} = \dfrac{A}{B + x_2^C} - Dx_1
$$

$$
\dfrac{dx_2}{dt} = E x_1 - Fx_2
$$

A->F are just constants. $x_2^C$ is just $x_2$ to the power of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linearisation of a system *at a certain point* is given by the Jacobian matrix of (the right hand side of) that system, evaluated at that certain point. In your case, you have a system of the form
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x_1}{\text{d} t} &= f(x_1,x_2),\\
 \frac{\text{d} x_2}{\text{d} t} &= g(x_1,x_2).
\end{align}
The Jacobian matrix at the point $(a,b)$ is therefore given by
\begin{equation}
 J = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a,b) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a,b) \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(a,b) & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}(a,b) \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In your case, the only difficult partial derivative is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$, but using the chain rule, you should be able to calculate that.